# best method for creating a print style sheet

Tags: css, printing, stylesheet

I'm writing a print style sheet for my website.  I've noticed that most modern browsers and even Internet Explorer have an option to print the page in a "Shrink to Fit" way.

I'm wondering is there a problem with writing the print css file so that target this print method OR is it better to target the 100% width setting?

It seems that Shrink to Fit is the default setting in IE9. Chrome uses Shrink to fit as the only way to print as far as i can tell. Firefox has, in my opinion, too many options.  You can set a custom width, shrink to fit (which BTW doesn't actually work in Firefox latest version, but this is a known bug so i'm with it not working there. Hopefully they fix it soon).

I've got the style sheet working great with Shrink to Fit option with IE9, Chrome, and Firefox set at 60% lo